# Dart : listview in itembuilder, multiple generate button for each element

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Got a little problem : I generate a listview (which works) o friends, but i want to add a button to add friends. Problem : it is takes and repeats for each element in the list :
[image]

Of course, i want only one button. How can i do this ?

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../models/chat_params.dart';
import '../../../models/userModel.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../RouteConsts.dart';

class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserList({super.key});

  @override
  _UserListState createState() => _UserListState();
}

class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<UserModelDataUser>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount:users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return UserTile(users[index]);
        }
    );
  }
}

class UserTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserModelDataUser user;
  const UserTile(this.user, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
    if (currentUser == null) throw Exception("current user not found");
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                fixedSize: const Size(200, 50), //For Fixed Size
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: ()  {
                showDialog<String>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text('This is a typical dialog.'),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15, width: 60,),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: const Text('Close'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("Container clicked");
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add friend'.toUpperCase(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            currentUser.theUid == user.uid?
              const Text("")
            :
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (currentUser.theUid == user.uid) return;
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                      context,
                      RouteConsts.chatScreen,
                      arguments: ChatParams(currentUser.theUid, user),
                    );
                  },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(user.pseudo),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
      ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I use a stateless widget.
Hope someone could help me... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeated button issue in your UserTile component is happening because you have placed the button within the Column widget that's inside the UserTile. This means that for every item in the ListView.builder, a new instance of the UserTile is created with its own Column, and thus, a new button is added.

Change your code like this

```
class UserList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<UserModelDataUser>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return UserTile(users[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}

class UserListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          // give the properties of your button
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: UserList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class UserTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserModelDataUser user;
  
  const UserTile(this.user, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
    if (currentUser == null) throw Exception("current user not found");
    
    if (currentUser.theUid == user.uid) {
      return const SizedBox.shrink(); 
    }
    
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        // give the card properties
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              RouteConsts.chatScreen,
              arguments: ChatParams(currentUser.theUid, user),
            );
          },
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(user.pseudo),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is any issues let me know. I don't know Exactly where in the other files it may make an issue in.